# How to refresh data

Tags: c#

I have renamed a file within a folder, but when I try to move the file to another location I receive an error message -

> File not found.

The file path still holds the old file name i.e. `c:\user\appFolder\OldFileName.txt`

But within the folder the file name has been changed to the `NewFileName.txt`

How do you refresh the data?

Code below

```
foreach (string filename in fileEntries)
{
    RenameFile(filename);

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
    string destinationPath = TransfersPath;

    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileName);
    System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile);
}
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. What does `RenameFile` do? Why loop through `fileEntries` and only use `fileName` as a destination for the same `sourcePath` for every entry? Seems like logic errors...

Comment: Well of course `fileName` isn't changing to the new name. There's nobody but you who can change it, and you didn't.

Comment: File system data does not need to be refreshed. When you call any file operations, the file system will be just like it looks in Windows Explorer. The problem is likely with your input strings to File.Move()

Answer (score 2):

It seems that calling method doesn't know the new filename.

So, You need to return new file name from RenameFile method

```
string newFilename = RenameFile(filename);
```

and use newFilename in the rest of the code instead of filename.